# Javascript event handler/requestAnimationFrame data race

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-events, requestanimationframe

I have two pieces of code. One is a `requestAnimationFrame` loop, which iterates over an array doing some computations on each element then rendering a scene. I also have an event handler for a button that modifies the state of the array (deletes some elements). The two pieces look something like this:

```
function update(delta) {
    var to_remove = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // Computations
        if (cond) {
            to_remove.push(i);
        }
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < to_remove.length; j++) {
        // This is where the error occurs, since j has been deleted.
        arr[j].some_field = null;
        arr.shift(j, 1);
    }
}
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    var new_time = Date.now();
    update(new_time - last_time);
    last_time = new_time;
    // Render scene
}
render();
```

My event handler just calls remove on an element of the array, `arr`:

```
$("#my_button").click(function () {
    arr[j].some_field = null;
    arr.shift(i, 1);
});
```

Every now and then I will get what seems like a data race: I will get an error from trying to delete an out of bounds index in the array which makes me think it was already deleted and that the `requestAnimationFrame` is running in a separate thread from the event handler and so the two are accessing the same data. Can anyone confirm/deny this or advise me on how to avoid these data races?

Comment: Try using `var j` in your second loop instead of declaring `i` twice...

Comment: What do you mean by `update(Math.min(17, new_time - last_time));` Also update function does not take parameter in you code. Update it to avoid confusion

Comment: Also why ++i for removal?

Comment: Updated to use j, update just takes a time delta over which to update, updated that. ++i avoids a copy that i++ does. Probably doesn't matter but I'm used to it from C++.

Comment: Where's the event handler code?

Comment: My guess is when there is only 1 element in to_remove, ++i would represent 1 instead of 0 and hence out of bound exception. Also preincrementing will skip 1st element.

Comment: Added event handler code. Also, ++i doesn't preincrement before the loop runs, it is identical to i++ in this instance. You should read up on pre/post increment.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad.